# Typedef an uintX_t type, where X is the value of a macro

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer

I have a macro, `WW`, with the word width in bits, like

```
#define WW 64
```

I want to declare a new type, `foo_t`, as an alias for one of the `uintX_t` in `<stdint.h>`. I can hard code the word width and use

```
#define uint(x) typedef uint ## x ## _t foo_t
uint(64);
```

However, `uint(WW)` is obviously an error. I have played around for a while using a macro like `#define expand(x) x` and use it in various ways, to no avail. My last resort is an `#if` cascade such as

```
#if WW == 64
typedef uint64_t foo_t;
#elif WW == 32
typedef uint32_t foo_t;
#elif WW == 16
typedef uint16_t foo_t;
#elif WW == 8
typedef uint8_t foo_t;
#else
#error "unsupported word width"
#endif
```

which I'd rather avoid. Is there a way to typedef a type based on my `WW` macro so that `uint(WW)` would expand eventually to `uint64_t`? I *believe* the answer is "no", but some language-lawyer please prove me wrong.

Comment: `stdint.h` types are to provide a **fixed** bitrate. What would be the point to reverse this?

Comment: @Olaf I'm writing a program that adapts to arbitrary word size (bitrate? You mean bit width?) It's a proof-of-concept type exercise.

Comment: Yes, typo, of course. I meant width. How about argument concatenation `##`?

Comment: @Olaf As described, I tried token pasting with ## already. The problem is it pastes WW, not its expansion.

Comment: Search around. You need a helper-macro. There have been some answers for this already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way macro expansion works, you need an extra level of indirection:

```
#define maketype(x) uint ## x ## _t
#define uint(x) typedef maketype(x) foo_t
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/LSOS30621)

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the correct answer. See also the section on "Argument prescan" in the manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html

Answer (score 2):

From C11dr n1570:

> #### 6.10.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>   argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
>   by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other
>   preprocessing tokens are available.

Basically, you need to do expansion through a caller macro:

```
#define WW 64

/* The macro that creates the typedef. */
#define uint_(x) typedef uint ## x ## _t foo_t

/* Replaces uint(x) with uint_(<expansion of x>). */
#define uint(x) uint_(x)

/* Replaces x with <expansion of x>. */
#define expand(x) x

uint(WW);
expand(uint_(WW));
```

results in

```
typedef uint64_t foo_t;
typedef uintWW_t foo_t;
```

In the case of `expand(uint_(WW))`, it expands to its only argument, meaning `expand(uint_(WW))` becomes `uint_(WW)`. Because it's a part of a single preprocessing token, `WW` is not expanded. For this reason, you could have `expand(expand(expand(uint_(WW))))`, and it still wouldn't work.

In the case of `uint(WW)`, it expands to `uint_(WW)`. However, the paragraph above states that the argument to `uint` is subject to macro replacement, so the result is actually `uint_(<expansion of WW>)` because the argument `WW` is macro replaced. The `uint_` macro is then invoked with the replaced value of `WW`.

The reason passing `WW` directly to the macro responsible for the `typedef` doesn't work is because `WW` is a part of an expression involving token pasting (`##`). "A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token ..., is replaced..." Basically this means that `##` prevents expansion.

You can't use `uint_(expand(WW))` either for the same reason: `typedef uintexpand(WW)_t foo_t` doesn't exactly look right, does it?

You can also accomplish this through a more generic `PASTE3` macro:

```
#define WW 64
#define PASTE3(x, y, z) PASTE3_(x, y, z)
#define PASTE3_(x, y, z) x ## y ## z

PASTE3(typedef uint, WW, _t foo_t);
```

Also, remember that because `WW` is an expression on its own, it will be completely macro replaced. This means that no matter how many levels of replacement there are, it will be expanded, unless `#` or `##` halts the expansion of course:

```
/* Try not to do silly things like this... */
#define YY(x) 6 ## x
#define WW YY(4)

#define PASTE3(x, y, z) PASTE3_(x, y, z)
#define PASTE3_(x, y, z) x ## y ## z

PASTE3(typedef uint, WW, _t foo_t);
```

results in:

```
typedef uint64_t foo_t;
```